# Undefined username in leaderboard command [ quick.db / discord.js ]

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, leaderboard, quick.db

I've tried making a leaderboard command with quick.db for my Discord.js bot but it isnt working.
It replies with undefined users and stuff like that!

```js
var money = await db.all(`money_${message.guild.id}`, { sort: ".data" });
    
let resp = "";
for (let i = 0; i < money.length; i++) {
    let user = client.users.cache.get(money[i].ID.split("_")[1]);
    resp += `${i + 1}. ${user} - ${money[i].data}$\n`;
}
    
return message.channel.send(
    new Discord.MessageEmbed().setAuthor(`Leaderboard`).setDescription(resp)
);
```

Here is the code ^^^^

Here is the output for the command

[image: Here is the output for the command (Image)]

Answer (score 0):

It means that `money[i].ID.split("_")[1]` is not a valid ID. Have you thought about logging these values in the loop to check the validity of the data you store?